# How to install apcu in windows

Tags: php, windows, apc

How can I install APCu in Windows?

I found [this](http://www.phpgangsta.de/apcu-der-neue-user-cache). But I need a solution for Windows.

I use PHP 5.5.6 (I have the XAMPP package).

Comment: Hi there user3481997! Robert's answer below is the correct one. The only difference for you is you are using XAMPP. In my case, the folder to copy the 'correct' dll is "C:\xampp\php\ext". Your XAMPP directory might be different. Check your PHP error log to make sure it installs correctly.

Answer (score 94):

[This](http://robert-rusu.blogspot.com/2014/06/install-apcu-on-windows.html) short and straight to the point tutorial should help you

## Install APCu on Windows

Assumptions

- I assume that you know what is APC - Alternative PHP cache
- You want to install APCu because APC is not compatible anymore with PHP 5.5.x
- You want to install APCu for wamp, xampp. Mostly windows web development platforms for PHP

Instructions

Pre: All directory locations might be different for you depending on your wamp installation folder and your PHP/apache versions.

1. Go to http://pecl.php.net/package/APCu, there is a table with available releases
2. Choose whatever release suits you better (latest stable version that supports your php version)
3. Choose package from DLL list, depending on what Windows you are using:

   - PHP version (5.5 in your case)
   - **x64** (64 bits) OR **x86** (32 bits windows)
   - Thread Safe (for Apache compatibility)
4. Unzip the archive, copy `php_apcu.dll` in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.6\ext`.
5. Go to `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin` open `php.ini` and add the following lines (I just added them at the end of the file):

   ```
   [apcu]
   extension=php_apcu.dll
   apc.enabled=1
   apc.shm_size=32M
   apc.ttl=7200
   apc.enable_cli=1
   apc.serializer=php
   ```

   This are recommended configurations located in INSTALL file from the php_apcu archive, excepting the location of the DLL file.
6. Restart wamp
7. Go to http://localhost/phpinfo.php and check if apcu configuration table appears and apcu is enabled
8. If you also want to use apcu for PHP CLI then you only need to add in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.6\bin\php.ini` the config lines you added at step 5 in apache's php.ini.

The end!

Comment: Do I need the thread-safe or non-thread-safe version if I'm hosting in IIS? Is there ever a time to choose NTS over TS?

Answer (score 14):

For those who want APCu with backward APC compatibility (1:1 replacement without changing codebase, for example `apc_cache_info` > `apcu_cache_info`)

1. Download `php_apcu.dll` from [release page](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/apcu/) (choose proper PHP version, architecture and thread safety mode)
2. Download `php_apcu_bc.dll` from [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/apcu_bc/)
3. Save both files in `ext` dir under your PHP installation folder
4. Load extensions in `php.ini`:

   ```
   extension=php_apcu.dll
   extension=php_apcu_bc.dll
   ```
5. Configure APCu in `php.ini`

   ```
   [APCu]
   apc.enabled=1
   apc.shm_size=32M
   apc.ttl=7200
   apc.enable_cli=1
   apc.serializer=php
   ```

INFO: APC extension with APCu-BC 1.0.3 must be named exactly `php_apcu.dll` in order to work. When I named it `php_apcu_bc-1.0.3-7.1-ts-vc14-x86.dll` XAMPP did not start properly (error about missing `php_apc.dll`)

Additional Note: the downloaded zip file from the source above for vc15 contained a file named php_apc.dll (in file: 'php_apcu_bc-1.0.4-7.2-ts-vc15-x86.zip' date: 13/06/2018) - just renaming it to php_apcu_bc.dll worked.

Comment: I did exactly what you said. When I downloaded the php_apcu_bc.dll it came with php_apcu.dll name still (from the PECL , point 2.) that you said), and I renamed it to that, and still doesn't fix it.

Errors:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_apcu.dll' 

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_apcu_bc.dll'

Comment: I'm sorry @JessicaPereira but it was 3 years ago and I'm not using Windows for development anymore. Unfortunately I can't help you more than giving a tip that you should check if you downloaded proper version of APCu (PHP version, architecture, thread safety etc.).

Comment: many many thanks. did exactly how u suggested and it worked: 1 -  downloaded php_apcu.dll for 7.3;ts | then 2 - downloaded php_apc.dll (that is apcu_bc) for 7.3;ts | then 3 - renamed php_apc.dll|pdb to php_apcu_bc.dll|pdb | finally added  extension = php_apcu.dll
extension = php_apcu_bc.dll to php.ini and restarted httpd - tested with phph -m = both apc and apcu modules running. you are the best, man!

Answer (score 1):

It matters if you use the thread safe or non thread safe version of the DLL. For me only the NTS worked in Windows 10 x64 and PHP 7.4 using the PHP built in server.
It was confusing because the error msg PHP gave when run php -i was *Unable to load dynamic library 'php_apcu.dll' (tried: ext\php_apcu.dll)* as if the file was not there.

Comment: Running a `phpinfo()` gives your version type (NTS or TS). Read it as "Thread Safety: Enabled (TS)" or "Thread Safety: Disabled (NTS)"

Answer (score -4):

Please refer to the official documentation:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php

In my case, I'm using PHP 5.6 on XAMPP
and everything I need to do is to update my `php.ini` file with (recommended settings):

```
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Comment: opcache is not APCu. opcache caches opcode, i.e. an intermediate code that is generated out of your php scripts. Any php script benefits from this (if its code does not change all the time). APCu is a data cache that allows php applications to cache data in memory. Only php scripts that explicitly use it benefit from this.